# Combine dataframes on columns containing repeated values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to combine two dataframes which both contain a column of repeated values but not the same number of repeats.

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,   1,   2,   2,   3,   3,   3],
                    'col2':[1.1, 1.3, 2.1, 2.3, 3.1, 3.3, 3.5]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,   2,   2,   3,   3,   3],
                    'col2':[1.2, 2.2, 2.4, 3.2, 3.4, 3.6]})

df1
   col1  col2
0     1   1.1
1     1   1.3
2     2   2.1
3     2   2.3
4     3   3.1
5     3   3.3
6     3   3.5

df2
   col1  col2
0     1   1.2
1     2   2.2
2     2   2.4
3     3   3.2
4     3   3.4
5     3   3.6
```

The desired output would be for example:

```
desired_result = pd.DataFrame({'col1':  [1,   1,   2,   2,   3,   3,   3],
                               'col2_x':[1.1, 1.3, 2.1, 2.3, 3.1, 3.3, 3.5],
                               'col2_y':[1.2, 'NaN' , 2.2, 2.4, 3.2, 3.4, 3.6]})
desired_result
       col1  col2_x col2_y
0     1     1.1    1.2
1     1     1.3    NaN
2     2     2.1    2.2
3     2     2.3    2.4
4     3     3.1    3.2
5     3     3.3    3.4
6     3     3.5    3.6
```

The problem is the ambiguity in how to combine the two dataframes on col1 which contains repeated values and a direct matching is not possible (and also not necessary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `groupby` and horizontal-`concat` each of the groups. After that, it's just some column/index manipulation:

```
In [75]: merged = df1.groupby(df1.col1).apply(lambda g: pd.concat([g[['col2']].reset_index(), df2[['col2']][df2.col1 == g.col1.values[0]].reset_index()], axis=1))

In [76]: merged.columns = ['_', 'col2_x', '__', 'col2_y']

In [77]: merged.reset_index()[['col1', 'col2_x', 'col2_y']]
Out[77]: 
   col1  col2_x  col2_y
0     1     1.1     1.2
1     1     1.3     NaN
2     2     2.1     2.2
3     2     2.3     2.4
4     3     3.1     3.2
5     3     3.3     3.4
6     3     3.5     3.6
```

Comment: Thank you very much @ami-tavory for you help. The first step with `groupby` and `concat` is great. However, the removal of the `NaN`'s removes some of the data. In the case of `col1==2` we have 3 numbers and 1 `NaN` in both `col_2x` and `col_2y`. With the current method to remove `NaN`s that simply drops all rows containing a `NaN` we loose some data.

Comment: @adabsurdum I forgot to `reset_index` when `concat`ing. See update.